# How do I disable compression in Filezilla?

Tags: ftp, filezilla, installed-programs

Normally in Windows I can do that in Edit>Options>SFTP, but I can't find the option in Ubuntu.

Comment: I think compression won't be taken in Filezilla, for both Windows and Ubuntu.